# R Loop by date calculations and put into a new dataframe/matrix

Tags: r, date, loops

I have a database with 7,994,625 obs of 42 variables.  It's basically water quality parameters taken from multiple stations every 15 minutes for 1 to 12 years depending on stations...

here is the head of dataframe:

```
    STATION       DATE       Time SONDE Layer TOTAL_DEPTH TOTAL_DEPTH_A BATT BATT_A   WTEMP WTEMP_A SPCOND SPCOND_A

1 CCM0069 2001-05-01 09:45:52     AMY    BS          NA           NND 11.6   <NA> 19.32    <NA>  0.387     <NA>
2 CCM0069 2001-05-01 10:00:52     AMY    BS          NA           NND 11.5   <NA> 19.51    <NA>  0.399     <NA>
3 CCM0069 2001-05-01 10:15:52     AMY    BS          NA           NND 11.5   <NA> 19.49    <NA>  0.407     <NA>
4 CCM0069 2001-05-01 10:30:52     AMY    BS          NA           NND 11.5   <NA> 19.34    <NA>  0.428     <NA>
5 CCM0069 2001-05-01 10:45:52     AMY    BS          NA           NND 11.5   <NA> 19.42    <NA>  0.444     <NA>
6 CCM0069 2001-05-01 11:00:52     AMY    BS          NA           NND 11.5   <NA> 19.31    <NA>  0.460     <NA>
 SALINITY SALINITY_A DO_SAT DO_SAT_A   DO DO_A   PH PH_A TURB_NTU TURB_NTU_A FLUOR FLUOR_A TCHL_PRE_CAL
1     0.19       <NA>   97.8     <NA> 9.01 <NA> 7.24 <NA>     19.5       <NA>   9.6    <NA>         63.4
2     0.19       <NA>   99.7     <NA> 9.14 <NA> 7.26 <NA>     21.1       <NA>   9.5    <NA>         63.2
 3     0.20       <NA>   99.3     <NA> 9.11 <NA> 7.23 <NA>     19.2       <NA>   9.7    <NA>         64.3
4     0.21       <NA>   98.4     <NA> 9.05 <NA> 7.23 <NA>     20.0       <NA>  10.2    <NA>         67.6
5     0.21       <NA>   99.2     <NA> 9.12 <NA> 7.23 <NA>     21.2       <NA>  10.4    <NA>         68.7
6     0.22       <NA>   98.7     <NA> 9.09 <NA> 7.23 <NA>     18.3       <NA>  11.0    <NA>         72.5
  TCHL_PRE_CAL_A CHLA CHLA_A COMMENTS month year day
1           <NA> <NA>   <NA>     <NA>   May 2001   1
2           <NA> <NA>   <NA>     <NA>   May 2001   1
3           <NA> <NA>   <NA>     <NA>   May 2001   1
4           <NA> <NA>   <NA>     <NA>   May 2001   1
5           <NA> <NA>   <NA>     <NA>   May 2001   1
6           <NA> <NA>   <NA>     <NA>   May 2001   1
```

I have been all though the R help sites and found similar questions but when I tried to addapt them to my dataframe no dice

I'm trying to 
loop by date and calculate total number of DO observations, number of times DO falls below 5 mg/l and then calculate % failure rate of 5mg/l.  I can do this over entire datasets and subset each station and date individually just fine but need to do this in a loop and put results in a new dataframe with other parameter calculations...  I guess I just need a head start..

Here is what little I have figured out or not .

```
x <- levels(sub$DATE)
for(i in 1:length(x)){


 x$c<-(sum(!is.na(x$DO)))/4  # number of DO measurements and put into hours(every 15 mins)
  x$dur<-(sum(x$DO<= 5))/4  # number of DO measurement under 5 mg/l and put into hours
x$fail<-(x$dur/x$c)*100    # failure rate at station and day

}
```

I get error codes about atomic vectors

What I eventually want is this

```
station      date        c  dur       fail
  HGD2115   5/1/2001    24  5   20.83333333
  HGD2115   5/2/2001    22  20  90.90909091
  HGD2115   5/3/2001    24  12  50
  JLD5564   5/1/2001    20  6   30
  JLD5564   5/2/2001    12  2   16.66666667
  JLD5564   5/3/2001    23  5   21.73913043
```

there are more calculations I need to do and add to the new dataframe such as the monthly min max and mean of salinity, temperature, etc...   hopefully I won't have to come back for help with that.    I just need some advice and push in right direction.

and eventually I will get really wild by throwing out days with not enough DO measurements!

Comment: Could you post one of the errors?

Comment: Look at this tutorial: http://rpubs.com/justmarkham/dplyr-tutorial. dplyr has exactly what you need with the group function.

Comment: x <- levels(sub$DATE)
> for(i in 1:length(x)){
+   y <- sub[sub$DATE == x[i],]
+   
+   y$c<-(sum(y$DO))/4
+ y$dur<-(sum(y$DO<= 5))/4
+ y$fail<-(y$dur/x$c)*100
+ 
+ }
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "c", value = 0) : 
  replacement has 1 row, data has 0

Comment: in mean time I will look into the tutorial!

Comment: Can you modify the question to include a fake data set, and then demonstrate the problem on the fake data.  Seems like you only have three variables, date/time, station, and DO.  And you want to determine the number of occurrences by day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like what you are asking (??)

```
# create sample dataset - you have this already
# 100 stations, 10 days, 15-minute intervals = 100*10*24*4
library(stringr)  # for str_pad(...) in example only - you don't need this
set.seed(1)       # for reproducible example...
data   <- data.frame(STATION=paste0("CMM",str_pad(rep(1:100,each=4*24*10),3,pad="0")),
                     DATE   = as.POSIXct("2001-05-01")+seq(0,15*60*24*1000,len=4*24*1000),
                     DO     = rpois(4*24*1000,5))

# you start here
result <- aggregate(DO~as.Date(DATE)+STATION,data,function(x) {
  count    <- sum(!is.na(x))
  fail     <- sum(x[!is.na(x)]<5)
  pct.fail <- 100*fail/count
  c(count,fail,pct.fail)
})
result <- data.frame(result[,1:2],result[,3])
colnames(result) <- c("DATE","STATION","COUNT","FAIL","PCT.FAIL")
head(result)
#         DATE STATION COUNT FAIL PCT.FAIL
# 1 2001-05-01  CMM001   320  147 45.93750
# 2 2001-05-02  CMM001   384  163 42.44792
# 3 2001-05-03  CMM001   256  119 46.48438
# 4 2001-05-03  CMM002   128   61 47.65625
# 5 2001-05-04  CMM002   384  191 49.73958
# 6 2001-05-05  CMM002   384  168 43.75000
```

This uses the so-called formula interface to `aggregate(...)` to subset `data` by date (using `as.Date(DATE)`) and `STATION`. For every subgroup, the column `DO` is passed to the function, which calculates count, fail, and pct.fail as you did.

When the function in `aggregate(...)` returns a vector, as this one does, the result is a data frame with **3** columns, one for date, one for station, and one containing the vector of results. But you want these in separate columns (so, 5 columns total in your case). The line:

```
result <- data.frame(result[,1:2],result[,3])
```

does this.

Comment: Thanks!  this has given me the push in the right direction i was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slight variation using the aggregate solution.  Instead of having the relational operator inside the aggregate function, a second data set is made consisting only of the data that satisfies the requirement (DO < 5).

```
set.seed(5)
samp_times<- seq(as.POSIXct("2014-06-01 00:00:00", tz = "UTC"), 
                 as.POSIXct("2014-12-31 23:45:00", tz = "UTC"), 
                 by = 60*15)
ntimes=length(samp_times)
nSta<-15
sta<-vector(nSta,mode="any")
for (iSta in seq(1,nSta)) {
  sta[iSta] <- paste(paste(sample(letters,3), collapse = ''), sample(1000:9999, 1), sep="")
}
df<-data.frame(DATETIME=rep(rep(samp_times,each=nSta)), STATION=sta, DO=runif(ntimes*nSta,.1,10))
df$DATE<-strftime(df$DATETIME, format="%Y-%m-%d")
df$TIME<-strftime(df$DATETIME, format="%H:%M:%S")

head(df,20)
do_small = 5
agr_1 <- aggregate(df$DO,list(station=df$STATION,date=df$DATE),length)
dfSmall <- df[df$DO<=do_small,]
agr_2 <- aggregate(dfSmall$DO,list(station=dfSmall$STATION,date=dfSmall$DATE),length)
names(agr_1)[3]="nDO"
names(agr_2)[3]="nDO_Small"

agr <- merge(agr_1,agr_2)
agr$pcnt_DO_SMALL <- agr$nDO_Small / agr$nDO * 100

head(agr)
```